# Can't Execute ReactiveCommand

Tags: xamarin, reactiveui

### In my Viewmodel

Property:

```
public ReactiveCommand IsManualFontOnClicked{get;}
```

Constructor:

```
this.IsManualFontOnClicked = ReactiveCommand.CreateFromTask(async _ =>  await SetManualFont());
```

### In my unit test

Notice I can't access Execute:

[image]

### Question

How do I execute the command from my unit test?
Note: I'm using ReactiveUI v8.0.0-alpha0117

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Rx 8.0 you would do `Command.Execute().Subscribe();` The Execute is Lazy in Rx 8.0.

Also worth noting you would have the property set as 
`public ReactiveCommand<Unit, Unit> IsManualFontOnClicked { get; }`

ReactiveCommand without the type specifiers is Legacy code

No need to have the Observable.Return etc.

Comment: I'm using `await sut.IsManualFontOnClicked.Execute().FirstAsync();` based on your help (and thanks) because I need to wait for the command to finish, otherwise I have to put logic inside the `Subscribe` method which I'm not a fan of.  I hope this is ok, It seems to work and I don't have to worry about having to use `Destroy()` of the subscribed subject which I'm still having trouble figuring out where to do in a unit test without using a `using` statement, which I also don't like.

Answer (score 1):

In ReactiveUI 7.x you can use

```
Observable.Return(Unit.Default).InvokeCommand(IsManualFontOnClicked);
```

I guess is the same in ReactiveUI 8